# Insert apostrophe in to SQL sever using php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL Sever` and wanting to insert special characters like apostrophe in to my database. As showing in the image bellow. Whenever I tried to insert a apostrophe, it gives me an error. (even if I type in double apostrophe `''` or `\'`). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php   
    $connInfo = array(
        'Database' => 'databasename',
        'UID' => 'user',
        'PWD' => 'password',
        'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true 
        );

    $connectString = sqlsrv_connect('sever.name.com', $connInfo) or die("Can't connect to the database.");

    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">Description info:<input id=\"Description\"  type=\"text\" name=\"Description\" \" >
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" /></form>";

    $Description = $_POST['Description'];   
    mysql_real_escape_string($Description);//even if I remove this part and write code to replace the text with double apostrophe, it wouldn't work
    echo "<br>Description is:".$Description."<br><br>";

    $query_update = "UPDATE ElectronicShop SET Description=NULLIF('$Description','') WHERE WorkOrder=5";
    $data = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $query_update) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));       
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Replace all single quotes(') with 2 single quotes('') before inserting.

Comment: Please, please, please read up on PDO or MySQLi and how to use parameterised queries rather than using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Look into PHP's [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) functions - Strangely enough, [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) seems to be what has worked for me in the past (using MySQL). Try either/or.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I have tired adding  `stripslashes()` and `addslashes()` in the place of `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It does the same thing and put a \ next to the `  but the effect is the same as shown in the image above, and I still get an error.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about php but parameterized queries are the way to go. You don't have to wrestle with escaping slashes and more importantly your sql is injection proof.